# Home Store View and Editing Home Link in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm not a web designer/coder but a friend had a designer quit on him and is needing some help getting his website up and running.

Website is www.wilfrednewman.com

They are using magento 1.7, blanco theme.

I'm wondering a couple things:

1) How to edit the first item of the menu (Clothing that leads to coming-soon.html). In the CMS Static Blocks he has page-menu defined which is where the other links are generated(bespoke,wedding,about,press,store), but Clothing is not there. I just don't know where to edit Clothing.

- I can go through the tutorial and see how to make nav_block1 for blanco ( http://www.techturn.com/TT/Blanco_Magento_Theme.pdf ), and I have successfully done that. It just adds a link to the end of the menu he already established. I think I could likely follow that to add all my links, but I just don't know how to edit the first link so it doesn't matter

2) How do I get a "storefront" view. Just some basic store-front that has the newest products listed? That's what I would want Clothing to link to.

Googling these problems generally brings me the wrong solutions, such as editing the Home button in the Magento Navigation, so I can't find the solution for what I need, so I'm sorry if this is common but I'm just not googling the right thing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Edit **Clothing** link,

`app/design/frontend/default/blanco/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml`.  I think he had added page-menu here.  Kindly check.

If you want to display products in clothing link, Add the below line in CMS Page (**coming-soon**).
Please change the category_id as you want.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="xx" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Wow this is great. Got it all edited. I don't know how I missed the top.phtml thing, probably because of how long I've been away from PHP, but that's what the search results always said to look at as well.

Comment: Hey, how would I make it the newest added products showing in this?

Comment: I think you are asking about display the new products in home page. If it is so, kindly follow this link:http://magentotutorial.net/display-products-home-page/.

Comment: None of these seem to work. I tried the all products and it didn't work. I'm on magento 1.7.

Comment: Hi, You have to Set Product as New from Date & Set Product as New to Date in your product page located in admin->Manage products